# Javascript Multidimensional Array Key-Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, multidimensional-array

I am doing an AJAX request to a JSON and getting following code as response:

```
{
  total: "1",
  items: [
    {
      id: 43,
      title: "ThisIsTheTitle",
      promoted: false,
      sticky: false,
      weight: 10,
      created: {
        timestamp: 1482054,
        formatted: "17/01/2017"
      },
      url: "http://...",
      airdate: {
        timestamp: 1484980,
        formatted: "17/01/2017"
      },
      video: {
        id: 43,
        number_of_views: 1,
        duration: {
          seconds: 50,
          formatted: "00:00"
        },
        required_login: false
      },
      program: {
        id: 25,
        url: "http://...",
        title: "ProgrammaTitel"
      },
      image: {
        uri: "public://...",
        full: "http://..."
      },
      tags: [
        {
          id: "4",
          name: "Map"
        },
        {
          id: "7",
          name: "Aflevering2"
        }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I push this data into my own JSArray. Note there is now only 1 response-item but more will be added.

I want to retrieve specific object-data based on the **name of a tag of the object** `(item > tags > name = 'Aflevering2')`

So I would like the data from the object where the tag name is `'Aflevering2'`.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are able to get the data (because you have shown it), but lets see what you have tried so far to access the element in question. Show your code (even with errors) please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the items with a combination of [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
obj.items.filter(v => v.tags.some(k => k.name === 'Aflevering2'));
```

```js
let obj = {
    total: "1",
        items: [
    {
        id: 43,
        title: "ThisIsTheTitle",
        promoted: false,
        sticky: false,
        weight: 10,
        created: {
            timestamp: 1482054,
            formatted: "17/01/2017"
        },
        url: "http://...",
        airdate: {
            timestamp: 1484980,
            formatted: "17/01/2017"
        },
        video: {
            id: 43,
            number_of_views: 1,
            duration: {
                seconds: 50,
                formatted: "00:00"
            },
            required_login: false
        },
        program: {
            id: 25,
            url: "http://...",
            title: "ProgrammaTitel"
        },
        image: {
            uri: "public://...",
            full: "http://..."
        },
        tags: [
            {
                id: "4",
                name: "Map"
            },
            {
                id: "7",
                name: "Aflevering2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

let items = obj.items.filter(v => v.tags.some(k => k.name === 'Aflevering2'));
console.log(items);
```

Comment: I assume `v => v.tags.some(k => k.name === 'Aflevering2')` is written shortened? How can I translate this code to 'full-length'? because I am getting this into my warnings: `arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use esnext option)` and I'd like to understand the code I write :)

Comment: @Kemagezien  it's an arrow function, it's not shortened. Google for arrow function js and the first result will explain it in deep.

Comment: thanks for information I did some research to arrow-functions. However e.g. Safari does not support arrow-functions. Is it possible to re-write this without an arrow-function?